# Debian 10 install cd not starting installer

Tags: debian, boot, uefi, bios

I am trying to install Debian 10 on my Acer desktop computer that does not have UEFI or Secure Boot. When I boot my Debian 10 installer CD, it gets to the menu where you choose graphical install, install, etc., but when I try to do anything, the computer beeps and the menu blinks and nothing happens. I also tried to start it in UEFI mode on my Dell laptop, and it started the installer just fine. Any tricks to fix this?

Comment: did you check BIOS for any security  options that might block the installer? how many times does the computer beep?

Comment: I've already installed Linux Mint 19 and Ubuntu 19.04 on it. It's the only OS installer that doesn't work in BIOS mode for me. It kind of looks like when I press install, it blinks some text in the bottom left corner. I'll look at it closer and try to figure out what it says. Also, it only beeps once.